# Are the Gearbox weapons supposed to be spec'd for Level 1?

Tags: borderlands-2

I just installed the additional DLC packs from the Borderlands 2 GOTY edition.  When I loaded my game, I got a notice that I now have some "Gearbox" branded weapons in my backpack.  However, they're really low capability.  For example, the damage ratings are:

```
11 for Gearbox Renegade Assault Rifle
11 for Gearbox Projectile Convergence SMG
41 for Gearbox Callipeen Sniper Rifle
```

Since I'm on my second playthrough in True Vault Hunter Mode, these weapons are useless.  Should they be spec'd according to my level, and this is a glitch, or is this how they are supposed to be delivered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These weapons are given once to every character, and yes, they're always all level 1 weapons. The intent is supposed to be to give new characters a small boost during the very first parts of the game where you'd normally only have a single crummy pistol. They just happen to also be given to existing characters unchanged when you buy the appropriate DLC.